# terraform template - how to use double curly braces

Tags: terraform

anyone knows how i can use

```
NAME_TEMPLATE=%{{service_name}}.%{{environment_name}}
```

In a Template file?
Everytime i want to use this terraform crashes - "%!s()".

I managed to escape '%' with '%%' but the double curly braces are still a Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Terraform 0.11 templating for generating docker-compose.yml for usage with rancher 1.
This is pretty outdated & special  but maybe someone benefits from it.

So i wanted to get the

```
NAME_TEMPLATE=%{{service_name}}.%{{environment_name}}
```

into my docker-compose.yml.

First i let the templating engine do its job with the yaml cause there were other variables to fill:

the Terraform template

```
data "template_file" "route53updater" {
  template = "${file("${local.templates_path}/docker-compose.yml")}"

  vars {
    aws_access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
    aws_secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
    aws_domain = "${var.instance_tld}"
    aws_zone_id = "${var.aws_zone_id}"
    aws_region = "${var.aws_region}"    
  }
}
```

```
version: '2'
services:
  route53:
    mem_limit: 134217728
    image: rancher/external-dns:v0.7.12
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY: ${aws_access_key}
      ROUTE53_ZONE_ID: ${aws_zone_id}
      AWS_REGION: ${aws_region}
      AWS_SECRET_KEY: ${aws_secret_key}      
      ROOT_DOMAIN: ${aws_domain}      
      TTL: '60'      
      NAME_TEMPLATE: "NAME_TEMPLATE_VALUE"
    expose:
    - '1000'
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.agent.role: external-dns
      io.rancher.container.create_agent: 'true'
```

becomes:

```
version: '2'
services:
  route53:
    mem_limit: 134217728
    image: rancher/external-dns:v0.7.12
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY: SECRET
      AWS_REGION: eu-central-1
      AWS_SECRET_KEY: SECRET
      ROOT_DOMAIN: domain.com
      ROUTE53_ZONE_ID: SECRET
      NAME_TEMPLATE: "NAME_TEMPLATE_VALUE"
      TTL: '60'
    expose:
    - '1000'
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.agent.role: external-dns
      io.rancher.container.create_agent: 'true'
```

And then i used replace to edit template contents inline like this:

```
resource "rancher_stack" "route53" {
  name           = "route53"  
  environment_id = "${var.rancher_environment}"
  scope          = "system"
  start_on_create = true
  docker_compose = "${replace("${data.template_file.route53updater.rendered}", "NAME_TEMPLATE_VALUE", "%{{`{{service_name}}`}}.%{{`{{environment_name}}`}}")}"
  rancher_compose = "${file("${local.templates_path}/rancher-compose.yml")}"  
}
```

so it replaces `NAME_TEMPLATE_VALUE` with `` %{{`{{service_name}}`}}.%{{`{{environment_name}}`}}")} ``